# Mousehover picture bigger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, keypress, mousehover

I want to make my picture bigger while holding down CTRL Key while hovering over the picture, and when I press CTRL again it is supposed to go back.

So I made that it would change all the pictures and then adds an eventlistener. The picture goes bigger with chrome extension but it doesn't respond to CTRL key response, not getting back to its original form.

```
    window.onload = function () {

   var srcList = $('img').map(function () {
    return this.src
  }).get() */
  var ctrlKey = String.fromCharCode(keyPress)
  // const ctrlKey = String.fromCharCode(event.buttonPress)
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
  // console.log(images)
  // var srcList = []
  // for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  //  srcList.push(images[i].src)
  // }
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var img = images[i]
    img.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
      // console.log(event)
      // if (!event.ctrlKey) { return }
      var el = event.target
      el.style.width = el.offsetWidth * 1.5 + 'px'
      el.style.height = el.offsetHeight * 1.5 + 'px'

      el.style.position = 'fixed'
      el.style.transition = '2s'
      // el.style.left = event.x + el.offsetWidth * 0.5 + 'px' 
      // el.style.top = event.y + el.offsetHeight * 0.5 + 'px'
      el.style.left = window.innerWidth / 2 - 0.5 * el.style.width.replace('px', '') + 'px'
      el.style.top = 0
      console.log(event)
    }, true)

    img.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
      const ctrlKey = String.fromCharCode(event.which)
      if (!event.ctrlKey) { return }

      console.log(event)
      var el = event.target
      el.style.width = el.offsetWidth / 3 * 2 + 'px'
      el.style.height = el.offsetHeight / 3 * 2 + 'px'

      el.style.position = 'relative'
      el.style.left = 0
      el.style.top = 0
    }, true)
  }
}

// Image.addEventListener(onmouseover, src('img')[, large]);

// var img = document.getElementById('image-hover')
```

Comment: I don't think you should add the eventListener to img ( this line: `img.addEventListener('keydown', function ...`), when you want it to go back to normal by pressing Ctrl. Try adding it to document or window? Do the images only grow when you mouseover **and** hold the Ctrl key? Or do they grow when you simply mouseover? Also note that `event.which` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

Comment: When you mosehover and hold crtl when hovering hover the pic.

Comment: Did you try binding the `keydown` eventListener to `window` or `document` instead of `img`, like I mentioned? (that is: substitue in that line `img.addEven...` for `document.addEventListener('keydown', function ...`)

Comment: Which page? The link I gave you was only to prove that `event.which` is deprecated and therefore should not be used

Comment: no it dosen´t change nothing it dosent change nothing if I but document.addEventListener('keydown', function ...) or Window.addEventListener('keydown', function ...)

Comment: If you also comment out this line `if (!event.ctrlKey) { return }`, does it work now? Even better, instead of commenting it out, try changing it to `alert("I've been listened!");`

Comment: I think this is the error: you're adding the eventListener to an element where the event won't be listened. You should attach it to `document` instead. Also, I think that line I mentioned will always make the function return, because `event.ctrlKey === undefined; !ctrlKey === true`. There is no `event.target` to change, you should `getElementsByTag('img')` and do a loop to restore the original size to each element, instead of using `event.target`. But I might be wrong, sorry I'm in a hurry and must leave now

Answer (score 0):

I have been tryng to change it but shows uexpected parsing error: unexpected token

```
window.onload = function () {
  // valid koik pildid
  // foreach pildidi ja igale pildile lisa eventlistener
  /* var srcList = $('img').map(function () {
    return this.src
  }).get() */
  // var ctrlKey = String.fromCharCode(keyPress)
  // const ctrlKey = String.fromCharCode(event.buttonPress)
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
  // console.log(images)
  // var srcList = []
  // for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  //  srcList.push(images[i].src)
  // }
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var img = images[i]
    img.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
      // console.log(event)
      if (!event.ctrlKey) { return }
      // const letter = String.fromCharCode(event.which)
      var el = event.target
      el.style.width = el.offsetWidth * 1.5 + 'px'
      el.style.height = el.offsetHeight * 1.5 + 'px'

      el.style.position = 'fixed'
      el.style.transition = '2s'
      // el.style.left = event.x + el.offsetWidth * 0.5 + 'px' // hiire koordinaadid
      // el.style.top = event.y + el.offsetHeight * 0.5 + 'px'
      el.style.left = window.innerWidth / 2 - 0.5 * el.style.width.replace('px', '') + 'px'
      el.style.top = 0
      console.log(event)
    }, true)

    //document.addEventListener('keyDown', function (event) {
    this.document.addEventListener("keyDown", checkKeyPress, false)
    function checkKeyPress(key){
        if(key.keyCode == "17"){
      //const CrtlKey = String.fromCharCode(17)
      // const ctrlKey = String.fromCharCode(event.keyDown)
      // if (!event.ctrlKey) { return }
      // alert('CrtlKey')

      // console.log(event)
        var el = event.target
        if (event.ctrlKey) {
        //alert("ctr key was pressed during the click");

        el.style.width = el.offsetWidth / 3 * 2 + 'px'
        el.style.height = el.offsetHeight / 3 * 2 + 'px'
        el.style.position = 'relative'
        el.style.left = 0
        el.style.top = 0
        }
      }, true)
    }
  }
}
// Image.addEventListener(onmouseover, src('img')[, large]);

// var img = document.getElementById('image-hover')
```